# How to create `DOS/Unix` Like GUI

Tags: c++, c, user-interface, unix

Assuming C/C++, I am wondering what kind of libraries should be used to create a DOS/Linux type of GUI? Please see the photos below (I do not know what is the official name of such a GUI as I never had to create one, but now I have to!). I am not asking for a complete tutorial....rather a point to start!

I need to have a static page and update some texts right in their place (no new line and stuff). Also some buttons and check-boxes, # filled progress bars, etc...

- DOS example:
  [image: MEMTEST-86]
- Linux example:
  [image: NVIDIA INSTALLER]

Comment: It is not a GUI, it is called TUI (Text User Interface). If you intended to make TUI for Unix-like operating systems like Linux, start with ncurses: http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/

Comment: Both examples you give are very peculiar. Do you need to write the UI for a user process? Or for embedded code? A BIOS? A disk clonner? Can you give more information about your platform?

Comment: A more common name would be [CLI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_interface). Being three and a half decades in the IT business, I actually had to google [TUI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text-based_user_interface)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is called as Text-based user interface (TUI) and here is the examples of programming libraries and wikipedia [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text-based_user_interface#Examples_of_programming_libraries).

I have some experience with ncurses in Unix/Linux environment. I think  [ncurses Programming HOWTO](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/) is a good place to start.

- [CDK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDK_(programming_library))
- [Dialog](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dialog_(software))
- [ncurses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses)
- [Newt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newt_(programming_library)), a widget-based toolkit
- [PDCurses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDCurses)
- [SMG$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMG$)
- [Turbo Vision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turbo_Vision)